# pgSQL order by desc not work correctly or what I did is wrong?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data store in a column as text

```
806,1250,1225,1080,1891,1878,1243,391,218,1505,1425,586,1801,860,323,1108,1130,1150,1060,1059
```

I want to select order by desc using this query

```
SELECT unnest(string_to_array(q.mycolumn, ',')) id FROM mytable q ORDER BY id DESC;
```

But the other now show correctly as bellow

> "860"
>   "806"
>   "586"
>   "391"
>   "323"
>   "218"
>   "1891"
>   "1878"
>   "1801"
>   "1505"
>   "1425"
>   "1250"
>   "1243"
>   "1225"
>   "1150"
>   "1130"
>   "1108"
>   "1080"
>   "1060"
>   "1059"

Comment: They are being ordered as strings, not integers.  8 > 3 > 2 > 1 regardless of length of string.  Same way 'dip' > 'anderson'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cast` to `int` to achieve the desired ordering. As you have it, the numbers are treated as characters.

```
SELECT unnest(string_to_array(q.mycolumn, ',')) id 
FROM mytable q 
ORDER BY cast(unnest(string_to_array(q.mycolumn, ',')) as int) DESC;
```

Comment: that solved my problems, but I use cast in select so it will return set of integer not a set of text.
SELECT  cast(unnest(string_to_array(q.mycolumn, ',')) as int) id 
FROM mytable q 
ORDER BY id DESC;